# Phonegap Service not Being called

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

Im running into a really weird error in 3.4 Phonegap/Cordova.

I have tested the service call through fiddler on the web as well as used WEINRE.

Over the browser it runs without any errors, when compiled to run on build.phonegap.com it hangs up on the first service.

The html

```
<!-- Page 1 -->
<div data-role="page" id="keyword" class="page">
<div class="bg"></div>
<div class="page-wrapper">
    <div class="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="" width="325" height="105"/></div>
    <div class="text1">Enter Code</div>
    <div class="input">
        <input type="text" name="keyword" placeholder="code" id="keyword-value" />
    </div>
    <div class="button" id="keyword-submit" >Submit</div>
    <div class="text2">
        If you do not have a<br>
        code, click continue
    </div>
    <div class="button" id="keyword-continue">Continue</div>
</div>
```

Im running into issues when running the keyword-submit function, it doesn't navigate through it though it does in the browser.

app.js

```
$("#keyword").live("pageinit",
        function()
        {
            $("#keyword-continue").click(
                function()
                {
                    $.mobile.changePage("#zip-code");
                });

            $("#keyword-submit").click(
                function()
                {
                    alert("Entered Keyword Submit");
                    var keyword = $("#keyword-value").val();
                    if($.trim(keyword) == '')
                    {
                        navigator.notification.alert('Please Enter code');
                        return false;
                    }
                    service.getListByKeyword(keyword,
                        function(response)
                        {
                            $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("loading"); 
                            var check = JSON.parse(response).responsecollection.Response.rss.rs;
                            if(check.isvalid == 0)
                            {
                                if (check.msg!=null)
                                {
                                    navigator.notification.alert(check.msg);
                                    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                window.localStorage.setItem("email",check.email);
                                alert("storing email");
                                service.resellerId = check.rsid;
                                localStorage.resellerId = service.resellerId;
                                alert("set reseller Id");
                                service.getResellerSetting(
                                    function(response)
                                    {
                                        alert("entered merchant");
                                        service.resellerEmail = JSON.parse(response).responsecollection.Response.rts.rt.mlid;
                                        localStorage.resellerEmail = service.resellerEmail; 
                                        var telefloraStatus = JSON.parse(response).responsecollection.Response.rts.rt.UseTeleflora;
                                        window.localStorage.setItem("floraStatus",floraStatus);
                                    });
                                    alert("Navigating to new page");
                                $.mobile.changePage("#keyword-list?keyword="+keyword);
                                //window.open("#keyword-list?keyword="+keyword,keywordPage);
                            }
                        });
                        alert();
                        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
                });
        });
```

I have set up alerts to see where its navigating in the browser and getting caught in the mobile side.

Last set of code is the index.js

```
  getListByKeyword: function (keyword, result) {
    service.sendRequest("Reseller", "IsValid", function(args) {
        args.rscode = keyword;
    }, result);
    alert("Inside the service call *END*");
}
```

I really cant seem to wrap my head around why it would work in the broswer and not on the android build.

Answer (score 0):

```
//please follow these steps to check your phonegap project is ready to perform action or not.
//1)include cordova js or phonegap file reference
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script> 
//2)check phonegap is ready or not
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        alert('ready');
    }
</script>
```

after that perform any action